# Difference between redirecting to a page and coming to the same page after pressing back button?

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

I have a page in which I am not using cache by using this code:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

Now I want to know: Is there any difference between coming to this page using a proper link or coming back using browser back button, or is there any way to detect this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no sure-fire way, but my guess is that using the back button, the HTTP referer is not set. Of course there are other reasons why the HTTP referer might not be set.

Answer (score 0):

I think that in the back button, the browser cache is used to get the page.  It's faster than using a proper link.

Comment: that i know but as i mention i am clearing the cache of that particular page